# Angularjs Form allows jump to next tab only if all fields of this tab is valid

Tags: html, angularjs

There is a form created using Angularjs,created a next button that jumps to next tab but dont know how to put check so that it first check all inputs and then jump to next tab if all valid.

next button performs 2 functionalities:-
1.checks all inputs are valid and required.
2.After checking,jumps to next tab if all valid and completly filled.